# Yii2 get absolute home url

Tags: php, yii2

I was trying to get the base url of my app build with yii2 I tried the following.

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl)) // Output string(0) ""
var_dump(Yii::getAlias('@web')); // Output string(0) ""
var_dump(Yii::$app->homeUrl); // string(10) "/dashboard"
var_dump(Url::base()); // Output string(0) ""
```

My URL is.
https://sub.sampledomain.com/dashboard/products
I want to get the "https://sub.sampledomain.com"

Any idea why all of this can't get the base URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Url::home()`, but with `$schema` parameter set to `true`:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

...

$absoluteHomeUrl = Url::home(true); // http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

For `https`, set `$schema` parameter to `https`:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

...

$httpsAbsoluteHomeUrl = Url::home('https'); // https://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

- [`Url` Helper docs (Guide)](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-url)
- [`yii\helpers\Url::home()` method](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#home()-detail) (API)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, but the result of code above for me is "https://sub.sampledomain.com/dashboard"